# Detect client disconnect in Python / Quart with websockets

Tags: python, websocket, quart

I have multiple clients, which I store in a list (connected).
When a client (browser) is closed, i want to remove this websocket from the list of connected websockets.

I've tried the method that pgjones wrote with some little alteration (https://medium.com/@pgjones/websockets-in-quart-f2067788d1ee):

```
    def collect_websocket(func):
        @wraps(func)
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            global connected
            data = await websocket.receive()
            data_json = json.loads(data)
    
            if data_json['msg_type'] == 'client_connect':
                if "id" in data_json:
                    new_client = Client(data_json['id'], False, websocket._get_current_object())
                    connected.add(new_client)
            try:
                return await func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                connected.remove(websocket._get_current_object())
            finally:
                for connect in connected:
                    if connect.ws == websocket._get_current_object():
                        connected.remove(connect)
                    break
        return wrapper
```

...

further in the code...

...

```
async def update_clients(self, input_survey):
        try:
            for client in connected:
                if client.survey_id == input_survey.identifier:
                    my_websock = client.ws
                    message = { ... some message...
                                }
                    message_json = json.dumps(message)
                    await my_websock.send(message_json)
        except:
            var = traceback.format_exc()
            constants.raven_client.captureException()
            self.logger.error('ERROR updating clients: {}'.format(str(var)))
```

In update_clients there should be some detection that the sending to a websocket that doesn't exist anymore goes wrong... and then remove it.
But there is no exception...?!

I also tried to:

```
try:
    await my_websock.send(message_json)
except asyncio.CancelledError:
    print('Client disconnected')
    raise
```

But still no exception occurred...

Comment: Its not clear what you think is going wrong here, does it work as you'd expect?

Comment: Hi pgjones, thanks for your reply. 
i want to know at the server side when a client is no longer there.
This so i can remove the client from the 'connected' list. 
What happens now,  is that the 'connected' list grows and grows over time in production. Whenever a connection is gone, it stays in the list. When a new connection is created by a client it is added as it is supposed to.

The purpose of 'connected' is to have only active websockets/clients in the list.

Comment: Could this be a simple issue with the `for` loop in the `finally` block, note how the break should be inside the `if` but isn't.

Comment: Oh i see, that is a copy paste issue to stackoverflow. I tested some more. On my local machine it works correct, so when a browser tab closes, it gets removed.
On my AWS ec2 it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

After updating quart and hypercorn to 0.9/0.6 the code works for browsers on a pc. (Firefox, Chrome)

But when i make a connection using an **iphone / ipad** and close it afterwards. The connection isn't removed!

Any suggestions why?